# Why did everything in space cool out?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, universe, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

Through my research, I learned that;

> According to thermophysics, heat always moves from an area of high
>   heat to an area of low heat. Space has no heat at all. It is extremely
>   cold

However, if I am not mistaken (I am not a physics guy), based on the `Inflation Theory`, the spaced expanded extremely fast. This is how physicists can explain the nearly exact same heat all over the space. What I am asking is:

- How inflationary theorists explain the same heat all over the space? Is it because that the total heat was scattered everywhere evenly and then cooled the same amount? If so, how come all space cooled down the same amount of heat?
- After the inflation and expansion, why did the hot plasma cool out? What is the reason?

Comment: Minor comment: Things don't have heat.

Comment: In inflationary theory, at the beginning of the universe, our universe nowadays was just a point. There was no matter ordinary matter, the only thing there was just vacuum energy and the nearly exponential growth of the universe was driven by the vacuum energy. Scalar field(s) (the most reasonable postulated source of vacuum energy) in space would fluctuate quantum mechanically (one of the source of temperature) and create anisotropies. However, these anisotrpies will be smoothed out due to inflation(you can interpret it as temperature fluctuation in space). no characters left, next comment..

Comment: There is a minimal level of fluctuation due to quantum effect no matter how fast it inflates. At the end of inflation, space no longer grow as fast as before, particles (excitation of matter fields) were created and the density anisotropies in space could no longer be diluted and they clump. As the universe further cool down (the average density of matter, radiation), atoms formed and then hydrogen cloud, heavier elements, molecules, planets... all the above so far are theories, but it turn out that they match quite well with observations.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply and I am sorry that I don't get it. Can you please simplify more?

Comment: Does anyone else find this ironic given that inflation theory was developed primarily to explain why the universe has the same temperature everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background_radiation)?

The CMB is a relic from when the universe became "opaque" - when, as Wikipedia says,

> protons and electrons combined to form neutral atoms. These atoms could no longer absorb the thermal radiation, and so the universe became transparent instead of being an opaque fog.

So photons [decoupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_(cosmology)) and the CMB was formed.

Curiously enough, the theory of [inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)) was posited to explain why the CMB was the same temperature throughout space (it also explains why, at the largest scales, the universe is homogenous - it appears the same).

> After the inflation and expansion, why did the hot plasma cooled out? What is the reason?

I assume you're talking about why the CMB cooled down. The answer is that the universe is expanding, and, therefore, the photons of the CMB are [redshifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) - just like how photons emitted from a source moving away are redshifted. As the photons are redshifted, they cool, and so the temperature of the CMB drops. If you're interested, this formula may be interesting:
$$T_f=2.725(1+z)$$
where $T_f$ is the temperature of the CMB and $z$ is the redshift. You can use this to calculate the temperature of the photons at any point in time - or, alternatively, if you know the temperature of the CMB, you can calculate the redshift at any point in time.